# Talend do not execute component at 0 rows

Tags: talend

I've filtred some data with a tFilterRow, it is working fine, but at O rows the flow with 0 rows continue executing components :

I have 2 queries at the end of filter and reject flows and both are executed !
I don't want my query to be executed at 0 rows
any help ?

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just for reference. `tJava` is a special component that always gets executed. It shouldn't be used with an incoming flow.

Here's a demonstration :
[image]

[image]

`tJava` and `tJavaFlex` have the same code. It gets printed in `tJava` but not in `tJavaFlex`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `Run If` trigger for your components. And put the trigger condition as per the criteria when you connect your one component to another stating that -

> execute the component only if the number of rows is greater than 0

Sample job layout - 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can also use global variable available in tFilterow like 1>((Integer)globalMap.get("tFilterRow_1_NB_LINE_OK")) and 2> ((Integer)globalMap.get("tFilterRow_1_NB_LINE_REJECT")). Create two link one with filter name and other with reject 
In if link just use this variables with condition like 
**for Filer link: - ((Integer)globalMap.get("tFilterRow_1_NB_LINE_OK")) > 0
for Reject link : - ((Integer)globalMap.get("tFilterRow_1_NB_LINE_REJECT")) > 0**